# "return false" doesn't work for jQuery post form submission when script is loaded from external source

Tags: php, jquery, redirect, post, submit

I have these two forms:

```
<form id='EnableBackgroundCrossfadeForm' action='BgCFenable.php' method='post'>
    <input id='BgCFenable' class='DisableD_Button' type='submit' value='Enable'>
</form>
```

and:

```
<form id='DisableBackgroundCrossfadeForm' action='BgCFdisable.php' method='post'>
    <input id='BgCFdisable' class='DisableButton' type='submit' value='Disable'>
</form>
```

And this is the external `POST.js` file:

```
$("#BgCFdisable").click(function(){

    $("#BgCFLog").animate({"max-height":"100px"}, 300);
    $("#BgCFLog").html("<img src='Resources/Images/Loader02.gif'/>");

    $.post($("#DisableBackgroundCrossfadeForm").attr("action"),
               $("#DisableBackgroundCrossfadeForm").serializeArray(),
               function(data){
                    if(data == "DISABLED"){
                        $("#BgCFLog").html("Background Crossfading disabled!");
                        $( "#BgCFdisable" ).attr("disabled", "disabled");
                        $( "#BgCFdisable" ).switchClass( "DisableButton", "DisableD_Button", 1000, "easeInOutQuad" );
                        $( "#BgCFenable" ).removeAttr("disabled");
                        $( "#BgCFenable" ).switchClass( "DisableD_Button", "EnableButton", 1000, "easeInOutQuad" );
                    }
               });
    $("#DisableBackgroundCrossfadeForm").submit(function(){
        return false;
    });
});

$("#BgCFenable").click(function(){

    $("#BgCFLog").animate({"max-height":"100px"}, 300);
    $("#BgCFLog").html("<img src='Resources/Images/Loader02.gif'/>");

    $.post($("#EnableBackgroundCrossfadeForm").attr("action"),
               $("#EnableBackgroundCrossfadeForm").serializeArray(),
               function(data){
                    if(data == "ENABLED"){
                        $("#BgCFLog").html("Background Crossfading enabled!");
                        $( "#BgCFdisable" ).removeAttr("disabled");
                        $( "#BgCFdisable" ).switchClass( "DisableD_Button", "DisableButton", 1000, "easeInOutQuad" );
                        $( "#BgCFenable" ).attr("disabled", "disabled");
                        $( "#BgCFenable" ).switchClass( "EnableButton", "DisableD_Button", 1000, "easeInOutQuad" );
                    }
               });
    $("#EnableBackgroundCrossfadeForm").submit(function(){
        return false;
    });
});
```

The main idea is that this work perfect if I put the script between `<script></script>` tags at the end of my `INDEX.php` file (where I have the forms) in the `body`. With other words this works just if the jQuery script is "internal" and not loaded from and external `*.js` file.

If is loaded externally, submiting the form will redirect me to the `BgCFenable.php/BgCFdisable.php` instead of remaining on the `INDEX.php` page, where I need the resulted data to be displayed.

How can I make this work loading the script externally without redirecting on submission?

Comment: Where is the <script src="POST.js"></script> tag located in your html page? It's at the same location as the original script?

Comment: don't put the submit handler code inside another event handler. Also far better not to use button events to submit ajax, but rather use the `submit` event of form

Comment: the script is placed in `head`. The INDEX.php and the two php files that I use to get response from are in the same folder. The external POST.js is placed in another folder.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out in the end.
Those are the forms:

```
<form id='EnableBackgroundCrossfadeForm' onsubmit='return EnableBGCF();'>
    <input id='BgCFenable' class='DisableD_Button' type='submit' value='Enable' disabled='disabled'>
</form>
```

and:

```
<form id='DisableBackgroundCrossfadeForm' onsubmit='return DisableBGCF();'>
    <input id='BgCFdisable' class='DisableButton' type='submit' value='Disable'>
</form>
```

And this is the external .js file:

```
function EnableBGCF() {
    $("#BgCFLog").animate({"max-height":"100px"},300);
    $("#BgCFLog").html("<img src='Resources/Images/Loader02.gif'/>");

    $.ajax({type:'POST', url: 'BgCFenable.php', data:$('#EnableBackgroundCrossfadeForm').serialize(), success: function(response) {
        $('#BgCFLog').html("Background Crossfading <span style='color: #c9e52d'>enabled!</span>");
        $( "#BgCFdisable" ).removeAttr("disabled");
        $( "#BgCFdisable" ).switchClass( "DisableD_Button", "DisableButton", 1000, "easeInOutQuad" );
        $( "#BgCFenable" ).attr("disabled","disabled");
        $( "#BgCFenable" ).switchClass( "EnableButton", "DisableD_Button", 1000, "easeInOutQuad" );
    }});

    return false;
}

function DisableBGCF() {
    $("#BgCFLog").animate({"max-height":"100px"},300);
    $("#BgCFLog").html("<img src='Resources/Images/Loader02.gif'/>");

    $.ajax({type:'POST', url: 'BgCFdisable.php', data:$('#DisableBackgroundCrossfadeForm').serialize(), success: function(response) {
        $('#BgCFLog').html("Background Crossfading <span style='color: #e52d58'>disabled!</span>");
        $( "#BgCFdisable" ).attr("disabled","disabled");
        $( "#BgCFdisable" ).switchClass( "DisableButton", "DisableD_Button", 1000, "easeInOutQuad" );
        $( "#BgCFenable" ).removeAttr("disabled");
        $( "#BgCFenable" ).switchClass( "DisableD_Button", "EnableButton", 1000, "easeInOutQuad" );
    }});

    return false;
}
```

Now it's working. Thanks for help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in the event for the click and prevent default so the form doesn't submit..

So, on:

```
$("#BgCFdisable").click(function(){...
```

You need to do:

```
$("#BgCFdisable").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();...
```

Same, on:

```
$("#BgCFenable").click(function(){...
```

You need to do:

```
$("#BgCFenable").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();...
```

Comment: return false has the same effect like preventDefault(), especially from a jQuery handler (http://stackoverflow.com/a/1357151/1974224) The problem here is that the same code works when added inline, but doesn't work when loaded from an external js