# jQuery ajax does not work

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I made a test jQuery ajax script and I attached it to a form when submitted but despite the fact that I have `return false` at the end of my function the page keep refreshing at submit and I also don't get any response.

The form look like this:

```
<form id="LogInForm" onsubmit="return LogIn();">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="Username"><br/>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="Password"><br/>
    <input id="LogIn" type="submit" value="Sign In">
</form>
```

The script look like this:

```
function LogIn() {

    $.ajax({
          type:'POST',
          url: 'login.php',
          data:$('#LogInForm').serialize(),
          success: function(response) {
                    alert(response);
                 }});
        return false;
       }
```

The `login.php` file only contains `echo "test";`

The `index.php` and `login.php` are in the same folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just removed the onsubmit from you'r form and implemented it into the script.

```
<form id="LogInForm">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="Username"><br/>
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="Password"><br/>
    <input id="LogIn" type="submit" value="Sign In">
</form>
```

script

```
$(function() {
    $("#LogInForm").submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
          type:'POST',
          url: 'login.php',
          data:$('#LogInForm').serialize(),
          success: function(response) {
               alert(response);
           }});
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's kinda strange because I have nearly the same code as the one that I posted (with the `onsubmit="return function();"` thing) in another project and it work. To be more specific, this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29460437/return-false-doesnt-work-for-jquery-post-form-submission-when-script-is-loade

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $("#LogInForm").submit(function() {  
        $.post('login.php', $("#LogInForm").serialize()).done(function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }); 
    });
});
```

and the html

```
<form id="LogInForm">
   <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="Username"><br/>
   <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="Password"><br/>
   <input id="LogIn" type="submit" value="Sign In">
</form>
```